# nock library - how to match any url

Tags: node.js

Hi I am trying out the [nock library](https://github.com/flatiron/nock/blob/master/README.md) but am struggling with matching random patterns on query strings. I thought something like the code below should work but I can not get anything to work.

```
  var nock, request;

  request = require('request');

  nock = require('nock');

  nock("http://www.google.com").filteringPath(/.*/g).get("/").reply(200, "this should work?");

  request("http://www.google.com?value=bob", function(err, res, body) {
    return console.log(body);
  });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I haven't used this before, but from reading the [docs](https://github.com/flatiron/nock#path-filtering) maybe this will help.

How about something like this:

```
var nock = require('nock');
var request = require ('request');

nock("http://www.google.com")
    .filteringPath(function(path){
        return '/';
    })
    .get("/")
    .reply(200, "this should work?");

request("http://www.google.com?value=bob", function(err, res, body) {
    return console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

We can use regexp too

```
nock("http://www.google.com")
   .get(/.*/)
```

Comment: This is still tied to google.com. Is there a way to match all endpoints at all hosts?

Comment: @IgorNikiforov, try use wildcard regexp instead of a string in the hostname. Based on [docs](https://github.com/nock/nock/blob/main/README.md#specifying-hostname) it should work

Answer (score 6):

Just to complete thtsigma's answer:

You can also add [Scope filtering](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#scope-filtering) if you want to **match any scope (protocol, domain and port)**

```
var nock = require('nock');
var request = require ('request');

nock("http://www.whatever-here.com", {
    filteringScope: function(scope) {
      return true;
    }
  })
  .filteringPath(function(path){
      return "/";
  })
  .get("/")
  .reply(200, "this should work?");

request("http://www.google.com?value=bob", function(err, res, body) {
  return console.log(body);
});
```

With this, any url will be matched.