# Testing async redux with third party API calls

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, redux, amazon-cognito, redux-thunk

I'm new to redux and programming in general and am having trouble wrapping my head around certain unit testing concepts.

I have some async actions in redux, which involve calls to a third party API (from the 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' node module).

I have wrapped the external API call in a promise function, and I call this function from the 'actual' action creator. So for testing I just want to stub the result of `externalAWS()` function so that I can check that the correct actions are being dispatched.

I'm using redux-thunk for my middleware.

```
import { AuthenticationDetails,
         CognitoUser
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

export function externalAWS(credentials) {

  //This is required for the package
  let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(credentials);

  let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
  //Construct the object accordingly
  })

  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: result => {
        resolve(result);
      },
      onFailure: error => {
        reject(error)
      }
    })
  }
}

export function loginUser(credentials) {

  //return function since it's async
  return dispatch => {

    //Kick off async process
    dispatch(requestLogin());

    externalAWS(credentials)
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch(receiveLogin(result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(), credentials.username))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(failedLogin(error.message, etc))
      })
  }
}
```

I don't have any test code yet because I am really not sure how to approach this. All the examples deal with mocking a HTTP request, which I know is
 what this boils down to, so am I supposed to inspect the HTTP requests in my browser and mock them out directly?

It's further complicated by the fact that the second argument of `authenticateUser` is not even a plain callback, but an object with callbacks as it's values.

Can anyone offer some advice on whether my intention in unit testing the async function is correct, and how I should approach it? Thank you.

Edit: I'm testing in Jest.

Edit2: Request Headers
[First POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDxCR.png), 
[Second POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d9XH.png)

Edit3: Split the function, trying my best to isolate the external API and create something that is 'easily mock/stub-able'. But still running into issues of how to properly stub this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out in the end.
First, I had to require() the module into my test file (as opposed to ES6 import). Then I removed the promise for now since it was adding a layer of complexity and combined everything into one function, let's call it `loginUser()`. It is a redux async action, that dispatches one action upon being called, and then a success or failure action depending on the result of the API call. See above for what the API call looks like.

Then I wrote the test as follows:

```
const CognitoSDK = require('/amazon-cognito-identity-js')
const CognitoUser = CognitoSDK.CognitoUser

//Set up the rest of the test

describe('async actions', (() => {
  it('should dispatch ACTION_1 and ACTION_2 on success', (() => {
    let CognitoUser.authenticateUser = jest.fn((arg, callback) => {
      callback.onSuccess(mockResult)
    })
    store.dispatch(loginUser(mockData))
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ACTION_1}, {ACTION_2}])
  }))
}))
```

So basically once requiring the module in, I mocked it in Jest and did a mock implementation too, so that I could access the onSuccess function of the callback object.

Answer (score 0):

Redux thunk gives you the ability to dispatch future actions within the context of a main action that kicks off the process. This main action is your thunk action creator.

Therefore tests should focus on *what actions are dispatched within your thunk action creator according to the outcome of the api request*.

Tests should also look at what *arguments are passed to your action creators* so that your reducers can be informed about the outcome of the request and update the store accordingly.

To get started with testing your thunk action creator you want to test that the three actions are dispatched appropriately depending on whether login is successful or not.

1. requestLogin
2. receiveLogin
3. failedLogin

Here are some tests I wrote for you to get started using Nock to intercept http requests.

**Tests**

```
import nock from 'nock';

const API_URL = 'https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'

const fakeCredentials = {
    username: 'fakeUser'
    token: '1234'
}

it('dispatches REQUEST_LOGIN and RECEIVE_LOGIN with credentials if the fetch response was successful', () => {

  nock(API_URL)
    .post( ) // insert post request here  e.g - /loginuser
    .reply(200, Promise.resolve({"token":"1234", "userName":"fakeUser"}) })

  return store.dispatch(loginUser(fakeCredentials))
    .then(() => {
      const expectedActions = store.getActions();
      expect(expectedActions.length).toBe(2);
      expect(expectedActions[0]).toEqual({type: 'REQUEST_LOGIN'});
      expect(expectedActions[1]).toEqual({type: 'RECEIVE_LOGIN', token: '1234', userName: 'fakeUser'});
    })
});

it('dispatches REQUEST_LOGIN and FAILED_LOGIN with err and username if the fetch response was unsuccessful', () => {

  nock(API_URL)
      .post( ) // insert post request here  e.g - /loginuser
      .reply(404, Promise.resolve({"error":"404", "userName":"fakeUser"}))

  return store.dispatch(loginUser(fakeCredentials))
    .then(() => {
      const expectedActions = store.getActions();
      expect(expectedActions.length).toBe(2);
      expect(expectedActions[0]).toEqual({type: 'REQUEST_LOGIN'});
      expect(expectedActions[1]).toEqual({type: 'FAILED_LOGIN', err: '404', userName: 'fakeUser'});
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps explain the ideas behind testing async action creators. However, my test still fails because the original `authenticateUser` function is still running. I know this because it's failing with an exception from the docs for this API ('User not found', presumably from 'fakeUser').

Comment: Incidentally, mocking the response is also the part I'm least familiar with, so I don't know how to troubleshoot from here.

Comment: What url is being requested when you make the api call?

Comment: There are a number of HTTP requests being made from `authenticateUser`. Specifically two POST requests made to https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Ok sorry I should have realised that this is the function we need to stub. I have updated the code in the example. Now the authenticateUser function should be mocked and therefore return the resolved promise we have defined in the tests. Run it and let me know if the real api is still being called. Since you haven't shared the amazon-cognito-identity-js file I don't think I can run the code for myself.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. To clarify, `cognitoUser` is an instance of the `CognitoUser` class defined in 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js), and `authenticateUser` is a class method. I've re-constructed it in the test, but the _actual_ unmocked `authenticateUser` is still being called in the test. Thanks for your efforts, I really appreciate it! I'll upvote your answer for now, but I would really like to figure out how to get the tests passing before accepting.

Comment: Perhaps jest doesn't work the way I thought. Ok seems like other people are using the nock library to mock http requests. I will rewrite the example to include the use of nock.

Comment: okay try the newly updated code and let me know what happens!

Comment: Forgive my noobness, but I can't find out what the POST request is... I'm currently getting a 'No match for request POST...'. Of the two requests I mentioned before, the first is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html .

Comment: Try this then and let me know how you get on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678580/nock-library-how-to-match-any-url

Comment: Alternatively can you upload this to a github repo so I can clone it and work through it with you?

Comment: On reflection, I'm not sure that cloning a repo with this would be much use, since you'd need an AWS account and a User Pool set up (I don't want to print my own details for this as it's a shared AWS account). However I have refactored the code in the original question, attempting to isolate the external API. I'm not sure how I would go about stubbing this 'wrapper' function though, any ideas? Thanks and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Hope you had a good new year. Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41534158/3946931

Comment: So I figured it out in the end, but thanks so much for your help!